# Navigation bar tint color changes after auto dimissal of UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uialertview

I have written my custom UIAlertview to allow auto dismissal in certain cases. Now, with iOS 7 when auto dismissal happens the tint color of my nav bar changes. As per the iOS7 Transition Guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/TransitionGuide.pdf

**When an alert or action sheet appears, iOS 7 automatically dims the tint color of the views behind it. To respond to this color change, a custom view subclass that uses tintColor in its rendering should override tintColorDidChange to refresh the rendering when appropriate.**

Any idea if this can be handled from with in the custom UIAlertView only. Below is my code for custom UIAlertView:

```
#define kStartupFailAlert 203

#import "RunnerUIAlertView.h"

@implementation RunnerUIAlertView

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(removeAlert) name:kRemoveVisibleAlert object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)removeAlert {  
    if (self.tag != kStartupFailAlert) { // If not kRunnerStartupFailAlert - as it will be auto dismissed
        self.delegate = nil;
        NSInteger aCancelButtonIndex = [self cancelButtonIndex];
        [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:aCancelButtonIndex animated:NO];
    }
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this worked out by restoring the tint settings on app delegate's window. But then it has this side effect of not dimming the navigation tint color when opening a popover or a sheet. It seems be an issue with iOS7 SDK.

```
- (void)removeAlert {
    if (self.tag != kStartupFailAlert) { // If not kRunnerStartupFailAlert - as it will be auto dismissed
        self.delegate = nil;
        NSInteger aCancelButtonIndex = [self cancelButtonIndex];
        [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:aCancelButtonIndex animated:NO];

        MyAppDelegate *appDeletgate = [Utilities applicationDelegate];
        appDeletgate.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
    }
}
```