# Tintcolor left back arrow navigationBar changes after closing UIAlertController (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, tintcolor

**EDIT: Custom code**
This problem was caused by setting the tintColor of all objects during the initial load of the application.

---

I have a very strange situation in my code. The tintColor of the left Back arrow is changing to another color after:

1. Presenting an UIAlertController
2. Closing the UIAlertController
3. Switching tabs. (The color changes can be seen during the tab switch).

After the color is changed, i can't set it back to the original color.

What did I try?

1) Setting the color back on multiple locations. (ViewWillAppear / ViewDidAppear).

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor  = UIColor.redColor()
```

2) Setting the appearance.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

3) Trying to override the method didSetTintColor

4) Change the tintColor after release of the UIAlertView (Example below)

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Example button", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in
        alertController.removeFromParentViewController()
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor  = UIColor.greenColor() 
})
```

5) Tried this solution:
[Navigation bar tint color changes after auto dimissal of UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711405/navigation-bar-tint-color-changes-after-auto-dimissal-of-uialertview)

Nothing seems to work. Could this be an IOS bug?
The weird thing is that the change won't happen after switching tab, but also doesn't happen when not using the UIAlertViewController.

Comment: what's the back icon color ? Yellow ?

Comment: The normal color is UIColor.whiteColor(). (I try setting different colors, to find the right place in the code).

The color is changed to a blueColor. (this is the default Tintcolor of the application)

Comment: Show switch tabs code

Comment: I edited the post!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `TintAdjustmentMode`,

```
 [self.view setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal];
```

or

```
 [self.view setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic];
```

Comment: Hi Lion, i tried this (Also in AlmanappDelegate.swift.) Nothing changes. When I set this to .Normal, the wrong color is displayed from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. In app delegate a function was setting all the tintColors of the whole app. Apparently the close of the ActionController will change the tintColors again

```
 for window in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
        window.tintColor = UIColor.wrongColor()
    }
```